# Python - if, elif, elif, else Statement Not Working as Expected

Tags: python, django, if-statement, http-referer

I'm using Django for a web site and needed to build a context processor to provide referrer (variable named `referer`)  information.

I have a simple if, elif, elif, else statement:

```
[ . . . ]

host = get_current_site(request)
local_url = SITE_URLS['local']
dev_url = SITE_URLS['dev']
prod_url = SITE_URLS['prod']

# print referer for debugging purposes - remove when done...
print("current host: {0}".format(host))
print("current urls: {0} {1} {2}".format(local_url, dev_url, prod_url))

# determine default referer - eg, set as host/site name
if host == prod_url:
    referer = prod_url

elif host == dev_url:
    referer = dev_url

elif host == local_url:
    referer = local_url

else:
    # set referer for current request
    try:
        referer = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']

    except KeyError as e:
        print('ERROR: key error - referer doesn\'t exist: {0}'.format(str(e)));

[ . . . ]
```

What's weird is that the print statements above yield the `host` being equal to the `local_url` (from console):

```
current host: http://localhost:8000
current urls: http://localhost:8000 [ . . . ]
```

Yet it is still evaluating the **else > try** and throwing a key error... The point is that only when the default host/site is not available, then the `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` is valid.

What is going wrong here? I'm missing something. Python is telling me that `host != local_url` but why?

**EDIT**

Thanks to a great hint from @Martijn Pieters. I changed the print statements and now see this:

```
current host: <Site: http://localhost:8000>
current urls: 'http://localhost:8000'
```

I think I forgot to use the attributes for the sites framework:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have a whitespace issue; replace your formatting with:

```
print("current host: {0!r}".format(host))
print("current urls: {0!r} {1!r} {2!r}".format(local_url, dev_url, prod_url))
```

to use `repr()` values instead; these will include more information on the type of the value and any trailing whitespace will be immediately obvious.

If you see a `django.contrib.sites.models.Site` object, compare against the `domain` attribute:

```
if host.domain == prod_url:
```

Comment: Yes, I now see that the value from the sites framework is different from the others. Doh! I've edited me question... Any tips for me to fix this?

Comment: what will ``!r`` do again? does it leave the whitespaces untouched?

Comment: @doniyor it is easy to miss trailing whitespace when printing a string; the `repr()` (`!r`) output gives you the string as a Python string literal, complete *with quotes* showing you where the string starts and ends; e.g. `foo` v.s. `'foo  '`.